# How can I create a virtual environment on Pydroid 3?

Tags: python, android, terminal, virtualenv, pydroid

I had tried it, but this was the result. Please check below.

```
cd /storage/emulated/0
mkdir venv3
cd venv3
virtualenv .
```

Output:

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python3.8' -> '/storage/emulated/0/venv3/bin/python'

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux) or something like that and your phone isn't root, go to your $HOME directory via one of these commands: `cd` or `cd $HOME`.
Then you can run `virtualenv .`.

You can't run some special things in your phone storage (if your phone isn't root), for example, you can't run a Bash script in `/storage/emulated/0/...`.