# Problems encountered when creating a virtual environment with Pydroid 3

Tags: python, android, python-venv

When I create a virtual environment with 'python -m venv env' in Pydroid 3, I get the following error message ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No70v.png)):

```
cd /storage/emulated/0/DocBlog
python -m venv env
```

Output:

```
Unable to symlink '/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/python' to '/storage/emulated/0/DocBlog/env/bin/python'

Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/DocBlog/env/bin/python'
```

... I've created an env folder, but it's missing several subfolders, including 'bin/activate'.

Yet Pydroid has unrestricted access to my data!

As a result, I can't activate my virtual environment.

How can I fix it?

[My screen]

I was expecting it to work like the Docstring tutorial I'm following on Django (*[La Formation Complète Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn0k9DDYBZM)*) or like any example of creating a virtual environment found on the Internet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and found the following post very useful to fix the issue which related to using the HOME folder. The response that was indicated (and which worked for me):

> If you are using Termux or something like that and your phone isn't root, go to your $HOME directory via one of these commands: `cd` or `cd $HOME`. Then you can run virtualenv (ArshakParsa).

[How can I create a virtual environment on Pydroid 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490413/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-environment-on-pydroid3)

Comment: What is the gist of it? [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to the user home folder? *Why* does that work? Why is it important? What is the idea?

Comment: From what ArshakParsa is indicating because of how permissions are set on the device, the only area that have the correct settings are those of your $HOME folder.

The only way you can bypass this is to root your android device, but this may void warranties etc.